# Gelfand's representation on matrices: construct maximal ideal in matrix algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ac.commutative-algebra, matrices, ideals

I would like to see a **constructive** proof (some algorithm?) of the following statement:

> Let $A_1, A_2, \dotsc ,A_k \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ be some **commuting** matrices, let $B$ be the commutative algebra (with identity) over $\mathbb C$ generated by $A_1, A_2, \dotsc, A_k$. Suppose $E \in B$ is not invertible, then $I = (E)$ is a proper ideal of $B$. There exists a maximal ideal $J$ of $B$ such that $I \subset J$.

I know we can prove the existence of maximal ideal of general commutative rings using the axiom of choice, but I think when dealing with concrete examples, a constructive proof can give us more insights.

In fact, I am trying to apply the proof Gelfand's theory of commutative Banach algebras to the special case of matrix algebras. The existence of maximal ideals is a key fact that estabilishes properties of Gelfand transform. In my experience, applying abstract proofs to concrete examples can always help us gain a better understanding. For example, I am very happy to see [a finite-dimensional version of Gelfand–Mazur theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653892/finite-dimensional-division-algebra-over-bbbc).

Actually I asked a somewhat related question [Construct maximal ideal in multivariate polynomial ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844573/construct-maximal-ideal-in-multivariate-polynomial-ring/4844588#4844588) in MSE, asking for constructive proofs for maximal ideals in multivariate polynomial algebra (since the matrix algebra is quotient algebra of multivariate polynomial algebra). However, the matrix algebra case is what I really concerned.

I have limited knowledges in algebra, so this may be a very simple question.

Comment: Well I just found a constructive proof of the weak form of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz using Grobner basis. I think it also provides a way to construct maximal ideals of multivariate polynomial ring directly. So it seems my question is solved, though I don't know are there better methods to deal with this particular case of matrix algebra. Also it seems impossible to develop a real algorithm from the constructive proof.